# I was trying to deploy my Python web application to Microsoft Azure, but it fails and I get this error on Github

Tags: python, azure, github, deployment, web-applications

> An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.
> Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
> Error: Deployment failed with error: Package deployment using ZIP deploy failed. Refer to logs for more details.

Comment: Did you check the logs for details?

Comment: I did check logs, There is nothing specific, but when I try to upload the application to the server, It collects all the libraries and download them, and this error occurs , I have mentioned the whole stack trace on Github link https://github.com/sdixit2/Sentiment_Analysis_IMDB_data/issues/1

Comment: `An unknown error has occurred.` Sounds like Azure is having trouble digesting Linux with its Azure virtual machine, Python and Unix.  Jokers in your deployment procedure are having you chase bugs in their debugging system which offers no information.  Sounds like a classic low-level goose chase for bubble up implimentationitis. We will need closer access to your deployment suite in order to find the bug in your debugging system.  http://reviewthecode.blogspot.com/2016/01/wtf-per-minute-actual-measurement-for.html  You have our sympathies, Make your time all your base.